# Python3 c api - python stops working

Tags: python-3.x, python-c-api

I was trying to get a list as an input. I've googled too. 
I built and installed my C-extension module in the command prompt .I am able to import the module but it did show few warnings.What it had shown me was.....

## At the CMD

```
D:\Python\c\summa>py setup.py build
running build
running build_ext
building 'saiyanism' extension
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.2612
8\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IE:\python\include
 -IE:\python\include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\
VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6
.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" "-
IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Fil
es\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\
include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.162
99.0\cppwinrt" /TcH.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\H.obj
H.c
H.c(63): warning C4133: 'function': incompatible types - from 'PyObject *' to 'c
onst char *const '
H.c(117): warning C4113: 'PyObject *(__cdecl *)(PyObject *)' differs in paramete
r lists from 'PyCFunction'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.2612
8\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID
=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:E:\python\libs /LIBPATH:E:\python\PCbuild\win32 "/LI
BPATH:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.1
3.26128\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x
86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBP
ATH:C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.16299.0\um\x86" /EXPORT:PyInit_sai
yanism build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\H.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.6\saiyanism.cp3
6-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\saiyanism.cp36-win32.lib
   Creating library build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\saiyanism.cp36-win32.lib and ob
ject build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\saiyanism.cp36-win32.exp
Generating code
d:\python\c\summa\h.c(112) : warning C4715: 'sumlist': not all control paths ret
urn a value
Finished generating code

D:\Python\c\summa>
```

## Here is my c module....

## H.c

```
#include "Python.h"
static PyObject* saiyanism(PyObject* self,PyObject* args)
    {
    const char* saiyajin;
    if(!(PyArg_ParseTuple(args,"s",&saiyajin))) return NULL;
    printf("Hello,%s.Glad to see a saiyan.\n",saiyajin);
    Py_RETURN_NONE;

    }
static PyObject* UI(PyObject* self)  //,PyObject* args)
{/*code here works properly*/
Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

static PyObject* set_all(PyObject* self,PyObject *target)//PyLong_FromLong(PyObject *item))
{
    /*some code and this too works*/
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

static PyObject* sumlist(PyObject* self,PyObject *args)
{
PyObject *pList;
PyObject *pItem;
Py_ssize_t n;
int i;

if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O!", &PyList_Type, &pList)) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "parameter must be a list.");
    return NULL;
}

n = PyList_Size(pList);

for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    pItem = PyList_GetItem(pList, i);
    if(!PyLong_Check(pItem)) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "list items must be integers.");
        printf("%ld",PyLong_AsLong(pItem));
        Py_RETURN_NONE;
    }
}
}

static PyMethodDef sups[]=
{
    {"saiyanism",saiyanism,METH_VARARGS,""},
    {"UI",UI,METH_NOARGS,""},
    {"set_all",set_all,METH_VARARGS,""},
    {"sumlist",sumlist,METH_VARARGS,""},
    {NULL,NULL,0,NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef saiyanismdef={
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "saiyanism",
    "sad",
    -1,
    sups
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_saiyanism(void){
Py_Initialize();
return PyModule_Create(&saiyanismdef);
}
```

## The problem is

when I try to import and run my sumlist function with a python list as parameter  Python immediately stops .

Here is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tKIa.jpg)

**I just started learning this, so if there are mistakes in my program please point them out.**

Should I Pass the arguement in a different way?Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see at least two mistakes in `sumlist`:

1. In the code

   ```
   if(!PyLong_Check(pItem)) {
       PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "list items must be integers.");
       printf("%ld",PyLong_AsLong(pItem));
       Py_RETURN_NONE;
   }
   ```

   you return `None` (the Python object) rather than the C `NULL` pointer, which is used to signal an error. You also attempt to print `pItem` using `PyLong_AsLong` - the one thing you know about `pItem` here is that *it is not a `long`*!
2. (The main error that is causing you problems) What happens when you get to the end of `sumlist` without any errors? You do not return anything and Python is expecting you to return a `PyObject*`. This is what the warning is telling you:

   > warning C4715: 'sumlist': not all control paths return a value

   A quick fix here would be to add `Py_RETURN_NONE` to the end of the function to return a `None` object to Python. However, you probably want to do something more useful....

Comment: Thanks but I am encountering a new error which says some sort of type error .......can you identify the mistake here again ....<code>long sum=0;</code> i declared it along with "int i" in sumlist and                                                                         
<code> sum=sum+ long (PyLong_AsLong(pItem));</code> I inserted this at the end of the for loop in sumlist right after the if statement's body.(This is the line that shows error.)